# list index out of range while trying to search for uri in search results from spotipy

Tags: python, google-sheets, spotify, spotipy

I made this program to convert a google sheets to a spotify playlist in python using spotipy.

But i have this error when trying to search for the uri in the search results (line 55), when this happens is random somtimes it happens at song 25 sometimes at song 400.

I have tried adding delays etc but nothing has helped.

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\###\OneDrive\Documenten\spotify playlist maker\maker\maker_v4.py", line 58, in <module>
    uri_results.append(search_results[i]['tracks']['items'][0]['uri'])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

code:

```
from re import S
import spotipy
from spotipy import SpotifyOAuth
import json
import gspread
import time

scope = 'playlist-modify-public'
username = '###'
#open google sheets credentials
sa = gspread.service_account()

#open google sheets client
sh = sa.open(input("Enter the name of the google sheet: "))
print("opened sheet:" + sh.title)

#open google sheets worksheet
wks = sh.worksheet(input("Enter the name of the worksheet: "))
print("opened worksheet:" + wks.title)

#open spotify credentials
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id="###", client_secret="###", redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1:8080/", scope=scope, username=username))


#create playlist
playlist_name = input("Enter playlist name: ")
playlist_description = input("Enter playlist description: ")

#fine playlist id
playlist = sp.user_playlist_create(user=username, name=playlist_name, public=True, description=playlist_description).get('id')


#get sheet data
sheet_songs = wks.get_all_values()

print(len(sheet_songs))
print("Playlist created")
print("Playlist name: " + playlist_name)
print("Playlist description: " + playlist_description)
print("Playlist ID: " + playlist)
time.sleep(2.5)
sheet_songs_uri = []
uri_results = []
search_results = []

for i in range(len(sheet_songs)):
    sheet_song = sheet_songs[i-1]
    print(i)
    search_results.append(sp.search(q=sheet_song, type='track'))

print(len(search_results))

time.sleep(5)

for i in range(len(search_results)):
    print(i)
    #print(search_results[i])
    uri_results.append(search_results[i]['tracks']['items'][0]['uri'])
    # sheet_songs_uri.append(uri_results)
    time.sleep(1)

sp.user_playlist_add_tracks(user=username, playlist_id=playlist, tracks=uri_results)

#print playlist info 
print("Playlist created")
print("Playlist name: " + playlist_name)
print("Playlist description: " + playlist_description)
print("Playlist ID: " + playlist)
```

Comment: range(len(sheet_songs)) user emumerate instead

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you exactly what the issue is.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\###\OneDrive\Documenten\spotify playlist maker\maker\maker_v4.py", line 58, in <module>
    uri_results.append(search_results[i]['tracks']['items'][0]['uri'])
                                      ^         OR          ^
```

Means the value you reference at that index isnt there...

I'd move this all into one loop.

```py
sheet_songs_uri = []
uri_results = []
search_results = []

songs = len(sheet_songs)
for i in songs:
    sheet_song = sheet_songs[i-1]
    print(i)
    result = sp.search(q=sheet_song, type='track')
    # Logic here to check if result actually has a value.
    if result:
        uri_results.append(results['tracks']['items'][0]['uri'])
    else:
        print('Error getting result')
```

Comment: tried this already, did not work, tried copying your code incase i made any mistake, did nit work. Same error